# ngrams text model with cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

In a ngram model (character ngram or bag-of-words), we need to ensure that the vocabulary of the test data is not use for fitting or training the model.

This is what sklearn TfidfVectorizer function doing with the two functions (fit and transform).

so, if I have a sklearn Pipeline model:

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ('svc', SVC())
    ])
```

and I pass it to a cross validation function:

```
cv = cross_val_score(model, data['text'], data['label'], cv=5, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
```

Does the cross_val_score follow the scenario (fit on training .. then, transform on test) in each fold?

or it just fit the model one time in the beginning (the first fold)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pipeline is run for each cv step so for each step of cv, tfidf fit is done only for train folds and transform for test and test fold

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
class Estimator(BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self,x,y=None):
        print ("inside fit:",x)
        return self
    def transform(self, x):
        print ("inside transform", x)
        return x
    def score(self,x,y):
        return 1
model = Pipeline([("e", Estimator()), ('l', linear_model.Lasso())])
cross_val_score(model, np.arange(15).reshape(3,5), np.arange(3), cv=3)
```